# Visual Webpart Registration form where data is stored to SQL Database table on button click

Tags: visual-web-part, visual

Please give the snippet for Visual Webpart where data is stored to SQL Database table.I'm able to store it in list but i need to store directly in SQL Server database table on submit.

Answer (score 3):

It same as you do in C# .net.

In your button click event, define a connection string and then insert command.

For eg.

```
Sqlconnection con=new Sqlconnection();

con.Connectionstring="Data Source=PHANNY-PC\PHANNY; Initial Catalog=db_stuRegisterPay; Integrated Security=SSPI";
string query="insert into Persons_info(perID, latinName, gender, dob, pob, phone, passport, curAdd, status) values('" + txtID.Text + "','" + txtLatinName.Text + "','" + cbGender.Text + "'" + dTPdob.Text + txtPob.Text + "','" + txtPhone.Text + "','" + txtPassport.Text + "'" + txtCurAdd.Text + "'" + cbStatus.Text + " )";

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
con.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close();
```

[Code example.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12611/easy-steps-to-insert-data-into-sql-server-using-Asp-NetC-Sharp.aspx)